# trying to get two parameters from url and add them into the next html page

Tags: javascript, parsing, drop-down-menu

I'm new to parsing urls. I hope to see what I am doing wrong and learn from it.

From one page a selection is made. A button is used to send the link with urlstring
html?w=2&p=1

w = website where the user is coming from
p = chosen package

w has to filled in in a input field (website)
p is a select field (package)

```
<script>
function processParameters()
{
    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    const websiteparams = urlParams.get('w')
    const packageparams = urlParams.get('p')
    if(websiteparams == 1) document.getElementById("website").innerHTML = "test1.com";
    if(websiteparams == 2) document.getElementById("website").innerHTML = "test2.com";
    select = document.getElementById("package");
    select.selectedIndex = packageparams;
}
</script>
```

I'm expecting that the input field website on my html form has the value test2.com and that the second package has been chosen

Only the website is not changed. The input field website is hidden, maybe this is the problem.
The package is chosen without any problems

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, not comparison.

Comment: changed into ==

Answer (score 0):

Problem here was the .innerHTML. I replace it with .value and now it works. The field is hidden and then .innerHTML doesn't work